# Excel macro unable to set Label Caption

Tags: excel, vba, label, caption

I have the follow macro for a button click. When I run it, I hit a snag at the Label caption line with an 'object required' error. The names of the objects are correct.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim objFileDialog As Object
    Dim objSelectedFile As Variant
    Set objFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
    With objFileDialog
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.*", 1
        .Title = "Select Input file"
        .Show
        For Each objSelectedFile In .SelectedItems
            Label2.Caption = objSelectedFile
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Object required`strongly indicates that there is no control`Label2`on the form! Add an  [Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-) to the top of the code module. Always use the keyword`Me`to refer to form members (from forms code module) as that indicates that it is not a variable and activates intellisense auto completion,

Comment: In the for loop you aren't referencing an object (label is a control). Assuming the Label2 control is on the `objFileDialog` just put a full stop (period) `.` before `Label2`.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Control is on an Userform and as code is in Userforms class module you can ommit an explicit`Me.`reference, it implicit uses it,but that can cause confusion (explicit`Me.Label2`would have caused a compile-time error).`objFileDialog`is an`Application.FileDialog`object that returns a collection of filenames in`:SelectedItems`.

Comment: @thanks for the clarity and info! I didn't realise this.